# Is it normally to use Latex editor as the only editor?

Tags: editors

Is it normally to use Latex editor as the only editor for producing the final document? One can think that working with the low level markup language (like tex) is quite complex task and that is why one can split the production process: use Word or OpenOffice Writer for the creative part of the work (fast typing down ideas) and use Tex editor for the final conversion of the Word document to the Tex source.

Comment: It is not only normal but also recommended. Doing a Word to TeX conversion is much more effort than doing proper markup from the beginning.

Comment: That is probably too open a question e.g. I use basic notepad for its even lower abilities to have no formatting at all then paste into  a tex editor where it can be tested so yes it is as you describe a two part approach

Comment: If you use Word, then don't use LaTeX, and vice versa. Reason: the conversion is really complicated and is often associated with errors.

Comment: i would use only LaTeX and editor of my choise (WinEdt). using them, it simple to write without any worry about form and conversion from Word to LaTeX. Simple and effective.

Comment: some  people write their text as markdown or word and then use e.g. pandoc to convert to latex. But this will only work if you format the source correctly, e.g. in word with word styles - "fast lazy typing" won't give something sensible.

Comment: @JouleV How complicated the conversion process will be, depends on how much formatting you add to you Word or Writer document. You can easily convert a light formatted Word document to LaTeX by using for example Pandoc, and then do the final typographical finishing in LaTeX. Word has for example an very good outlining mode. However, the most important is to avoid doing lot of markup when doing the creative work.

Comment: You don't need a LaTeX editor to use LaTeX and you don't need a word processor to write text.

Comment: Take a look at [LyX](https://www.lyx.org)

Comment: I just use the  editor emacs for everything (tex, text files, program code, ...), it's simpler that way. I don't think I have ever used Word to write a document, just use it as a reader if someone sends a document in that form.

Answer (score 7):

As phrased, I think this is probably a question that should be closed as too opinion based (I mean, what is "normal"). But if you mean "what are the advantages and disadvantages to writing directly in LaTeX", it seems fairer.

In practical terms you have these options:

1. Write the basic *text* in a WYSIWYG word-processor, then import that into LaTeX. It's quite hard to see any clear advantages to that. If you don't use the WYSIWYG processor to do the formatting, you are effectively just writing text. And word processors are not really very good text editors. If you happen to like them, that's fine, of course. But I wouldn't say it was "normal", or that there was any obvious reason to prefer Word or OpenOffice over Emacs, Vim, Sublime, Atom, or the TeX-specific editors.

   Also you lose some of the advantages of LaTeX this way, such as citation handling. And it gives you an additional stage, where you have to import your text and mark it up.
2. Write in Word (or whatever), or in Markdown, including only **simple** formatting (like italics, sectioning, and so forth) and then convert that document to LaTeX, probably using `pandoc`. So long as the formatting is simple and essentially semantic--not an attempt to fix precise fonts, sizes, and so forth--this will usually work, and some people prefer it because they find the LaTeX "cruft" gets in the way of clear thinking. The difficulty with it in my experience is that even a good converter will usually require some post-conversion manual intervention and adjustment, except with a simple document. And it is complex documents that have the maximum amount of cruft! Also getting converters to produce documents in exactly the form you like them is itself a deal of work.
3. Write directly in LaTeX, in any editor you choose. Editors which are designed to work with LaTeX, or have packages or modes that help them do that, simplify a lot of formatting, and often help to make the LaTeX "code" aspects of the text fade reasonably into the background. They usually have compiling systems which help automate the various compilation steps. (Some people use Lyx, which gives, as I understand it, a sort of semi-WYSIWYG type of interface, but which I cannot comment on.) You will, however, have to get used to seeing some macros and environments in your text.

I would (nearly) always choose option 3, because in my experience it's tedious to try to make a complete separation between "writing" and "formatting", because even the cleverest converters are never perfect, and because there are many features of LaTex (such as labels and citations) that I cannot cleanly separate from the writing process and want to have to hand as I write. I'd much rather write LaTeX in a suitably specialised editor with sensible code folding, shortcuts, syntax highlighting and so forth. I'd always rather do this than use a word processor, which I would only use if I know that the final document will have to be in Word, in which case the tedium of conversion works the other way, and the line of least resistance is simply to embrace the <strike>horror</strike> experience.

I do understand the desire to keep some aspects of the code "out of sight". So for long documents I will always split into separate files (which means preambles and things like that are kept hidden in ordinary writing), and I'd always leave some of the most messy aspects (like indexing) to the end. But that is really a personal thing. Mostly the "bulk" of a LaTeX document consists simply of text, and the code-y bits are confined to a few areas: keeping them in separate files helps. For similar reasons I will often split out code-heavy sections (such as complex tables or diagrams) to separate files. I find that a good editor helps me do this, and therefore helps to keep the working file clean.

The only time I will use a non-LaTeX format to start with, for a document that I think may well end up compiled to LaTeX, is if I am writing a document that I know I may want to produce in more than one format. In that case, I will use a suitable and convertible intermediate format -- either orgmode or Markdown. I'm not a mathematician, but if I was I think I'd probably want always to use a format in which I could include LaTeX math code directly.

I'd certainly strongly counsel against trying to write anything complicated in a word processor and then converting it to LaTeX; it's almost certainly going to be a painful process.